# Data is not binding to android recyclerview

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am new to android. I am trying to download data using the Github api and display in and infinite scrolling RecyclerView, the JSON data is been parsed, but somehow the data is not been attached to the recyclerview. 
Here is the code below:

```
Developer_RV_Adapter.java
package com.davidshare.githubdevelopers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by GemShare on 9/6/2017.
 */
public class Developer_RV_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
    private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;
    private boolean isLoading;
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private List<Developer> developerList;
    Context context;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public Developer_RV_Adapter(Context context, List<Developer> developerList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.developerList = developerList;
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if(!isLoading && totalItemCount<=(lastVisibleItem+visibleThreshold)){
                    if(mOnLoadMoreListener!=null){
                        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setmOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener){
        this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
    }

    @Override
    public  int getItemViewType(int position){
        return developerList.get(position) == null? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM){
            View developerView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.developer_list_item, parent, false);
            return new DeveloperViewHolder(developerView);
        }else if(viewType== VIEW_TYPE_LOADING){
            View loadingView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress_bar_item, parent, false);

            return new ProgressViewHolder(loadingView);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.w("binder function", "Just entered the binder");
        Developer developer = developerList.get(position);
        if(holder instanceof DeveloperViewHolder){
            DeveloperViewHolder developerViewHolder = (DeveloperViewHolder) holder;
            developerViewHolder.gitNameTv.setText(developer.getGitUsername());
            Log.w("binder ", developer.getGitProfileUrl());
            developerViewHolder.gitUrlTv.setText(developer.getGitProfileUrl());
            developerViewHolder.gitPicUrlTv.setText(developer.getGitProfilePicUrl());
            Log.w("profile pic", developer.getGitProfilePicUrl());
            Picasso.with(developerViewHolder.gitNameTv.getContext()).load(developer.getGitProfilePicUrl()).transform(new RoundedImage(2)).fit().centerCrop().into(developerViewHolder.profilePicImgV);
        }else if (holder instanceof ProgressViewHolder) {
            ProgressViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (ProgressViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.loadingProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return developerList == null ? 0 : developerList.size();
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        isLoading = false;
    }

    public class DeveloperViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView gitNameTv;
        TextView gitUrlTv;
        ImageView profilePicImgV;
        TextView gitPicUrlTv;

        public DeveloperViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            gitNameTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.developerName);
            gitUrlTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.developerUrl);
            profilePicImgV = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.developerPic);
            gitPicUrlTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.developerPicUrl);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent i = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), Profile.class);
                    i.putExtra("profile_name", gitNameTv.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("profile_url", gitUrlTv.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("profile_pic_url", gitPicUrlTv.getText().toString());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ProgressBar loadingProgress;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            loadingProgress = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.loading_progress_bar);
        }
    }
}



DeveloperList.java
package com.davidshare.githubdevelopers;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeveloperList extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Developer> developerList;
    Developer_RV_Adapter developer_rv_adapter;
    Developer developer;
    RecyclerView developerRV;
    private static final String GIT_BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:";
    private static int page = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_developer_list);
        developerRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.developer_rv);
        developerRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        developerList = new ArrayList<>();
        getDevelopersData(prepareQuery("java", "lagos", page));
        developer_rv_adapter = new Developer_RV_Adapter(DeveloperList.this, developerList, developerRV);
        developerRV.setAdapter(developer_rv_adapter);
        developer_rv_adapter.setmOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                developerList.add(null);
                developer_rv_adapter.notifyItemInserted(developerList.size()-1);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        developerList.remove(developerList.size()-1);
                        developer_rv_adapter.notifyItemRemoved(developerList.size());
                        getDevelopersData(prepareQuery("java", "lagos", page));
                        developer_rv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        developer_rv_adapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
```

the getDevelopersData method uses volley to query the github api and parse the JSON response into a List

```
    public void getDevelopersData(String requestUrl) {
        StringRequest jsonSringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String jsonResponse) {
                try {
                    JSONObject gitJSONOBject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                    JSONArray gitItemsArray = gitJSONOBject.getJSONArray("items");

                    for (int i = 0; i < gitItemsArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject developerObject = gitItemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        developer = new Developer(developerObject.getString("login"),
                                developerObject.getString("html_url"),
                                developerObject.getString("avatar_url"));
                        developerList.add(developer);
                        Log.w("developer_data ", developer.getGitUsername());
                    }
                    Log.w("JSON DATA", "getting the json data");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.e("Volley error", volleyError.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonSringRequest);
    }
//get the location and language and the page of the api data you want to load
    private String prepareQuery(String language, String location, int page){
        this.page++;
        String queryUrl = GIT_BASE_URL+location+"+language:"+language+"&page="+page+"&per_page=50";
        Log.w("Query URL = > ", queryUrl);
        return queryUrl;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to notify adapter in getDevelopersData() after data add to array list like add this line **developer_rv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of notifyItemInserted() inserted use

```
notifyItemRangedChanged(fromIndex,toIndex);
```

This will notify the adapter that some set of data is changed among the whole data and it tells the adapter that adapter should refresh the data and reload it into the recyclerView starting from fromIndex to toIndex as passed into the method.

If all data are changed then use :

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

if only one dataItem is changed then use :

```
notifyItemChanged(dataPosition);
```

Also I think this statment is causing problem.Try to remove this statment and check again.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    developerList.remove(developerList.size()-1);
                    developer_rv_adapter.notifyItemRemoved(developerList.size());
                    getDevelopersData(prepareQuery("java", "lagos", page));
                    developer_rv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    developer_rv_adapter.setLoaded();
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: nothing wrong with this part of the code, it works well

Comment: adding handlers without reference sometimes cause problems..so I said

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by just adding developer_rv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); just below developerList.add(developer); this notifies the adapter that new items have been added to the list.